# Give Powershell the output of a command as if it was a string

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm using Powershell to script the deletion of printers and their drivers. I'm calling the `Printing_admin_scripts` that are located in the System32 folder on Windows 7+. These scripts generate a LOT of output, and I'd like to capture the output (throw away most of it), and generate my own output, depending on the status.

> Why can't you use `$LASTEXITCODE`?

Cause these scripts do not generate any exit codes! They always represent 0.

My goal is to look for `"0x80041002"` in the output of the command. If so, do this... If not, do that. Below is what I've tried, but failed:

```
.\prnmngr.vbs -d -p "$_" | findstr "0x80041002" | out-null
        If ($LASTEXITCODE = 0) {
            Write-Host "$_ does not exist"
        } else {
            Write-Host "$_ removed"
        }
```

I also tried:

```
& .\prnmngr.vbs -d -p "$_".ToString() | findstr "0x80041002" | out-null
        If ($LASTEXITCODE = 0) {
            Write-Host "$_ does not exist"
        } else {
            Write-Host "$_ removed"
        }
```

This hides the output, but always prints that the printer was removed, even if it did not exist (which normally outputs "0x80041002"). My goal is to find that string, even though it's not written to the host (hopefully), then write my own text in place, and continue on.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 x64 so this might be the difference, but a quick test if  `prnmngr.vbs` really only returns 0 [showed me that I get different exit values](https://pastebin.com/bvrhPnFi). When I call the script without any arguments I get `1` as exitcode. Whereas I see a `0` if for example I pass `-g` (get default printer)

Comment: Powershell has a .tostring() method. Have you tried that?

Comment: @music2myear I tried that, but either I'm not doing it right, or it doesn't work. Updated question with testing that method

Comment: @nixda I seem to get 0 all the time, with or without parameters....? I'm also on Windows 10

Comment: can you edit the script to output to a text file, search that for the string, then delete the text file?

Comment: @CanadianLuke Have you tried the PS script from my link? (With `-g` and without any parameter). It calls the VBS script via `& cscript.exe`. Maybe that's the difference. I would have had expected the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the **PowerShell** logic to use `-eq` rather than `=` within the [if](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html) condition. Doing this will help ensure your conditional commands execute as expected based on the `$LASTEXITCODE`.

### If Command Syntax

```
If ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "$_ does not exist"
} else {
    Write-Host "$_ removed"
}
```

---

### Further Resources

- [If](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html)
- [Comparison Operators](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-compare.html)

Comment: @CanadianLuke .... Please note I looked over this with detail just as you explained and I observed the exact same behavior as you explained until I made that adjustment based on what I put in the answer I wrote which made it echo the correct message.

Answer (score 1):

Storing the result in an array is working for me:

```
$script = "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs"

$result = cscript $script -g

if($result -match 'foo') {
    write-host "match"
}
else {
    write-host "no match"
}
```